# Botões Active X

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu tenho um botão (ActiveX  - Commandbutton) numa planilha que eu gostaria que mudasse de cor ao passar o mouse pro cima.

Fiz o seguinte o código abaixo, ele até muda de cor mas não volta a cor anterior:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8000000D

End Sub
```

Como fazer pra mudar de cor quando apenas passar o mouse por cima?

Comment: Olá! Esse botão está em um formulário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, @Hudson!

A solução é um pouco mais simples que parece.

Basta colocar um Label transparente atrás, um pouco maior que o botão pode ser 2 pixels para cada lado.

Esse label estará com visible = true mas com backstyle = 0 - FrmBackStyleTransparent

E aí você insere o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8000000D
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8000000F
End Sub
```

O truque aqui é que colocando o label maior que o botão, assim que o mouse entra no Label significa automaticamente que cruzou uma das fronteiras do botão, então você reseta a cor : )

Isso funciona tanto nas sheets quanto em userform e você não depende de nenhum evento a mais

Comment: topppp obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Acredito que não era exatamente o que você queria , mas o máximo que consegui fazer foi o seguinte:

Ao passar o mouse, muda a cor como você fez.

Em seguida, ao clicar de volta em qualquer célula da planilha, usando o Worksheet_Selection Change, o botão voltar para a cor original ou a qualquer outra cor de preferência:

```
Sub changecolor(bt As CommandButton)

    bt.BackColor = &H8000000D

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Call changecolor(CommandButton1)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8000000F
CommandButton1.ForeColor = &H80000012

End Sub
```

Espero que, ao menos, se aproxime do que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado!!! Ajudou e muito!